# Dynamicaly inserted select elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My dropdown lists food types, once an item is selected another dropdown is displayed and gets populated with associated foods (fetched from database using *jQuery* and AJAX).

Now when I add another field (for multiple pickings), the type picked from the previous dropdown carry over to the appended dropdown affecting both fields. This must have something to do with manipulating arrays but I can't seem to get my head around the logic and code structure of it.

Here is my code:
HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="orderStrip">
    <a href="" id="addStrip">Add Row</i></a>
    <form action="phpfunctions/ReservationManagement/addReserve.php" method="post" id="addOrderForm">
        <div>
        <select name="type[]" class="selectOrder">
        <option value="">Choose a type</option>
        <option value="single_lunch">Single Order Lunch</option>
        <option value="toppings_lunch">Rice Toppings</option>
        <option value="extra_lunch">Extras Lunch</option>
        <option value="single_bfast">Single Order Breakfast</option>
        <option value="budget_bfast">Budget Order Breakfast</option>
        <option value="extra_bfast">Extras Breakfast</option>
        <option value="carbon_drink">Carbonated/Fizzy Drinks</option>
        <option value="non_carbon_drink">Non-Fizzy Drinks(Juice/Milk/Water)</option>
        <option value="breads_confection">Breads/Biscuits Confection(M.Y.SAN/Lemon Square, etc..)</option>
        <option value="sweets_confection">Candies and Sweets Confection</option>
        <option value="packed_snacks">Packed Snacks(Chippy, Piatos, etc..)</option>
        <option value="cooked_snacks">Cooked Snacks(Turon, Hotdog, etc..)</option>
        </select>
        <select name="item[]" class="selectItem">
        <option> Choose a type first </option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Qauntity">
        <input type="number" name="total[]" class="total"></input>
        <a class="removeStrip"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JQuery and Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var insert = 1;
    $("#addStrip").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    $("#addOrderForm").append('<div><select name="type[]" class="selectOrder"> <option value="">Choose a type</option> <option value="single_lunch">Single Order Lunch</option> <option value="toppings_lunch">Rice Toppings</option> <option value="extra_lunch">Extras Lunch</option> <option value="single_bfast">Single Order Breakfast</option> <option value="budget_bfast">Budget Order Breakfast</option> <option value="extra_bfast">Extras Breakfast</option> <option value="carbon_drink">Carbonated/Fizzy Drinks</option> <option value="non_carbon_drink">Non-Fizzy Drinks(Juice/Milk/Water)</option> <option value="breads_confection">Breads/Biscuits Confection(M.Y.SAN/Lemon Square, etc..)</option> <option value="sweets_confection">Candies and Sweets Confection</option> <option value="packed_snacks">Packed Snacks(Chippy, Piatos, etc..)</option> <option value="cooked_snacks">Cooked Snacks(Turon, Hotdog, etc..)</option> </select> <select name="item[]" class="selectItem"> <option> Choose a type first </option> </select> <input type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Qauntity"> <input type="number" name="total[]" class="total"></input> <a class="removeStrip"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>');
        insert ++;
        alert(insert);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.removeStrip', function(f) {  f.preventDefault();
            alert("remove");
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            insert--; });

});
$(document).on("change", ".selectOrder", function() {
    var list = $(".selectOrder").val();
        $.ajax({
        url:"phpfunctions/MenuManagement/getMenu.php?filter="+list+"&action=fetch",
        success:function(data){
        $('.selectItem').html("<option>Select a menu item</option>"+data);
        }
    });
});
$(document).on("keyup", ".quantity", function() {
    var list = $(".selectOrder").val();
    var item = $(".selectItem").val();
        $.ajax({
        url:"phpfunctions/MenuManagement/getMenu.php?filter="+list+"&compute="+item,
        success:function(data){
        $('.total').val(data*$(".quantity").val());
        }
    });
});
```

And finally, PHP:

```
if (!(isset($_GET["filter"]))){
    $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_canteen","root","");
    $result=$con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE status = 'Available' ORDER BY name");
}else{
    if(!(isset($_GET["compute"]))){
        if ($_GET["filter"]=="single_lunch"){
        $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_canteen","root","");
        $result=$con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE type = 'single_lunch' AND status = 'Available' ORDER BY name");

    }else if($_GET["filter"]=="toppings_lunch"){
        $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_canteen","root","");
        $result=$con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE type = 'budget_lunch' AND status = 'Available' ORDER BY name");

    }else if($_GET["filter"]=="extra_lunch"){
        $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_canteen","root","");
        $result=$con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE type = 'extra_lunch' AND status = 'Available' ORDER BY name");

    }else if($_GET["filter"]=="budget_bfast"){
        $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_canteen","root","");
        $result=$con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE type = 'budget_bfast' AND status = 'Available' ORDER BY name");

    }else if($_GET["filter"]=="single_bfast"){
        $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_canteen","root","");
        $result=$con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE type = 'single_bfast' AND status = 'Available' ORDER BY name");

    }else if($_GET["filter"]=="extra_bfast"){
        $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_canteen","root","");
        $result=$con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE type = 'extra_bfast' AND status = 'Available' ORDER BY name");

    }else if($_GET["filter"]=="carbon_drink"){
        $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_canteen","root","");
        $result=$con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE type = 'carbon_drink' AND status = 'Available' ORDER BY name");

    }else if($_GET["filter"]=="non_carbon_drink"){
        $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_canteen","root","");
        $result=$con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE type = 'non_carbon_drink' AND status = 'Available' ORDER BY name");

    }else if($_GET["filter"]=="breads_confection"){
        $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_canteen","root","");
        $result=$con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE type = 'breads_confection' AND status = 'Available' ORDER BY name");

    }else if($_GET["filter"]=="sweets_confection"){
        $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_canteen","root","");
        $result=$con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE type = 'sweets_confection' AND status = 'Available' ORDER BY name");

    }else if($_GET["filter"]=="packed_snacks"){
        $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_canteen","root","");
        $result=$con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE type = 'packed_snacks' AND status = 'Available' ORDER BY name");

    }else if($_GET["filter"]=="cooked_snacks"){
        $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db_canteen","root","");
        $result=$con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE type = 'cooked_snacks' AND status = 'Available' ORDER BY name");

    }
    if(isset($_GET["action"])){
        $rows=$result->rowCount();
        if ($rows > 0){
        while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo '<option value="'.$row["name"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<option>No results to display</option>';
        }
```

And here is how it looks, sorry, imgur takes too long to load for me. http://oi66.tinypic.com/2dsej4n.jpg
http://oi66.tinypic.com/307xo8y.jpg

Oh and excuse my poor coding sense, optimization and lack of design. I wanted to complete every basic function first, plus I'm still a beginner. Thanks!

Comment: you can just use PDO parameters to pass your values into the SQL query, instead of all those repetitive if-else statements. Then you can just write the query once.

Comment: Mind giving me a quick sample for reference? I'm only a beginner at this, at best.

Comment: There are so many tutorials... https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=PDO+parameters+tutorial&oq=PDO+parameters+tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57.5644j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure i completly understood your question, but as far i see is here:

`var list = $(".selectOrder").val();`

You are picking the value by class name, but i guess you should do it with `this` keyword, to pickup value from changed select.
`var list = $(this).val();`

And also at setting value to the select:

`$('.selectItem').html("<option>Select a menu item</option>"+data);`

Would be:

`$(this).next().html("<option>Select a menu item</option>"+data);`

Is this what you need?

Comment: Will try this and give you feedback good Sir. Honestly feel stupid for not thinking of this beforehand.

Comment: $(this).next() doesn't seem to be targeting the next select element. There's only two of them though, I wonder why.

Comment: Heyo, quick update, I did it but with a different method. I called the ajax result outside of the main ajax function and the $(this).next() worked! Thanks guy.

Comment: But i guess you would some day to change it from ajax, to do it, i guess this was occupated by ajax, so what you need to do, declare variable `var element=$(this);` before ajax call, and in ajax call it as `element.next()..` and it should work also. Best regards.